# Is implementing a function in an interface class possible?

Tags: php, oop, class, implementation

What is implementing a function? normally, what I know is implementing an interface which has

```
function foo();
```

and implementing like

```
function foo($bar)
```

in another class

but what happens when I implement the function in the interface? do I have to reimplement them in the subclasses? or can I use them in subclasses directly, assuming they are implemented in the subclasses.

```
interface ibarbar{
function foo($bar)
{ 
 return $bar.$bar;}
}

class barbar implements ibarbar
{
 function baz()
 {
 $this->barbar(); //used without implementing in subclass. expected results unknown.
 }
}
```

PHP documentation says

```
// This will not work
// Fatal error: Class BadTemplate contains 1 abstract methods
// and must therefore be declared abstract (iTemplate::getHtml)
class BadTemplate implements iTemplate
{
    private $vars = array();

    public function setVariable($name, $var)
    {
        $this->vars[$name] = $var;
    }
}
```

so all methods in an interface are abstract methods. but I couldn't find how to extend a function. or implement a function

Comment: I thought that the point of an interface was that you weren't implementing... If you're trying to use functions in child classes, wouldn't you just need a "parent" class?

Comment: I believe when you do that, it's an [abstract class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** implement a function in an interface. You can only specify its signature.

---

If you want to specify signatures for some methods but provide implementation for others, use an abstract class:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract public function B($c);

    public function C($d) {
        // do something
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public function B($c) { // need to implement B, as it is abstract
        $this->C($c);       // but can directly use C, as it is not
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An interface has no implementation, by definition.
You're talking inheritance, here, if you have a function having an implementation that you override / Shadow in another class.